# Checking out a remote git repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have to check out a repository (not mine) but I cannot see it. eg. `https://<server_name>/<class_name>/userid.git`.

The class instructor has made me the master developer on the project website that contains the above git repository.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try and clone that repo, with the credentials you using to connect the repo hosting server (which could be a GitLab instance, or Gogs, or ...)

```
git clone https://<yourLogin>@<server_name>/<class_name>/userid.git
<enter your Git server account password>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to create a local repository of the project.

- Install Git in your system from https://git-scm.com/downloads
- After Installing, go to any local folder in your system.
- Right click and select "***Git Bash Here***". It will open a terminal.
- write "***Git clone (link of the project)***"(without quotes).
- It will create a local repository of the project in your system.